# Data with image is not sending to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

After click on submit this code is not sending data to database. can you help.
also tried POST method.

these are my table name: in database.

```
id (AI),
image, 
name,
 dob, 
fathername, 
fatheroccupation, 
college, 
jscgpa, 
sscgpa, 
sscmaingpa, 
address, 
contact, 
email, 
homecontacts
```

I have tried different methods but none of them are working. Or can you please suggest me some GUI form builder for windows which i can use to create form that can send data to database?
my codes are given below.
I am currently learning php so new to this field.

```php
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect ('localhost','root','','admission');
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Admission Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//auto expand textarea
function adjust_textarea(h) {
    h.style.height = "45px";
    h.style.height = (h.scrollHeight)+"px";
}
</script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>



<body>

<div class="form-style-3">
<form action="" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <img border="0" alt="HOME-Mathreck" src="logo.png" width="50%" height="50%" class="logo"><br><br>
<fieldset><legend><b> Photo</b></legend>
    <label for="image"><span>Upload Your Photo: <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="file" class="input-field" name="image" id="image" /></label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset><legend><b>Personal Information</b></legend>
    <label for="name"><span>Name: <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="name" value="" /></label>

    <label for="dob"><span>Date of Birth: <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="date" class="input-field" name="dob" value="" /></label>

    <label for="fathername"><span>Father Name: <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="fathername" value="" /></label>

    <label for="fatheroccupation"><span>Father Occupation:: <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="fatheroccupation" value="" /></label>

    <label for="college"><span>College Name: <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="college" value="" /></label>
</fieldset>


<fieldset><legend><b>Education Information</b></legend>
    <label for="jscgpa"><span>JSC GPA: <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="jscgpa" value="" /></label>

    <label for="sscgpa"><span>SSC GPA: <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="sscgpa" value="" /></label>

    <label for="sscmaingpa"><span>SSC GPA (without 4th): <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="sscmaingpa" value="" /></label>

</fieldset>

 <fieldset><legend><b>Contacts Information</b></legend>

    <label for="address"><span>Address: <span class="required">*</span></span><textarea name="address" class="textarea-field"></textarea></label>
     <label for="contact"><span>Contact Number: <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="contact" value="" /></label>

    <label for="email"><span>Email: <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="email" class="input-field" name="email" value="" /></label>

    <label for="homecontacts"><span>Guardian Contact Number: <span class="required">*</span></span><input type="text" class="input-field" name="homecontacts" value="" /></label>
</fieldset>


<fieldset><legend><b> Confirm</b></legend>
    <h3><span>&nbsp;</span>Click to Submit</h3>
    <label><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" /></label>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php

    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $dob = $_GET['dob'];
    $fathername = $_GET['fathername'];
    $fatheroccupation = $_GET['fatheroccupation'];
    $college = $_GET['college'];
    $jscgpa = $_GET['jscgpa'];
    $sscgpa = $_GET['sscgpa'];
    $sscmaingpa = $_GET['sscmaingpa'];
    $address = $_GET['address'];
    $contact = $_GET['contact'];
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $homecontacts = $_GET['homecontacts'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO addata VALUES (?,$image, $name, $dob, $fathername, $fatheroccupation, $college, $jscgpa, $sscgpa, $sscmaingpa, $address, $contact, $email, $homecontacts)";
    $data = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if($data)
    {
        echo "Form Sucessfully Submited Contact Office Now";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error Submitting";
    }

?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score -1):

The following issue is occurring as you're probably trying to store the image ***instead of*** the path of the image.
There are two approaches to the solution, see what suits your requirements best and go with it
**Approach 1:**
Ask for the user to give the URL of the desired image instead of asking to upload it via the form.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Image Url.." name="[Enter desired name]" />
```

and you can store it in a `VARCHAR` or a `TEXTFIELD` datatype in the database.

**Approach 2:**
You can get image upload and store it on your server and then store the path to the database.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
You can use this as a reference or alter according to the need and later store it's location to the server.